# Visibility of identifiers between Oracle 10g and 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, ora-00904

I have a query with a subquery within a subquery. The inner subquery relates on the result of the outer query:

```
SELECT
    employees.ENAME,
    employees.DEPTNO,
    (
        SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT DNAME FROM DEPT WHERE DEPT.DEPTNO = employees.DEPTNO)
    ) DNAME
    FROM EMP employees 
;
```

For Oracle 10.2.0.1.0 it works fine, but Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 throws an error:

> ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEES"."DEPTNO": invalid identifier"

If I remove the query in the middle, it also works with Oracle 11. So I think this is a issue with the visibility of the identifier.

The code above is a simplification of my problem. For some reason, I can't solve the problem with another join, and I can't use stored procedures or auxilary views. How can I make this code work with Oracle 11 within a single query?

Comment: Please include the exact DB versions.

Comment: Not an issue with `12.1.0.2`

Comment: According to @LalitKumarB answer, the best solution is to either contact Oracle support or to apply latest patchset for 11g.

Comment: What you've shown doesn't work in 10.2.0.5 either, possibly because of the back-porting ibre5041 mentioned. You can't reference an identifier (your employees alias in this case) more than one level of subquery down.  Without seeing a more realistic, unsimplified, example and the restrictions you're working with it's hard to say how to work around it - why you can't join, why you have the extra level of subquery that is redundant in the example, whether you can use a CTE...

Comment: added Oracle versions to the question

Comment: Possibly bug 15990897 or 9509294, which is fixed in 12.1..?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to 10g ver. 10.2.0.5? 11g is really more restrictive about identifiers and some queries stopped working. These changes were also back-ported to terminal patchset (10.2.0.5). BTW:

- DNAME is used as column alias/name "twice"
- You use `SELECT *` in a place where you can return only one column
- The innermost query has no alias

I think Oracle is somehow confused about the identifier names and possibly the error message is misleading and the problem is somewhere else.

What about:

```
SELECT
    employees.ENAME,
    employees.DEPTNO,
    (
        SELECT X.DNAME FROM
            (SELECT D.DNAME FROM DEPT D WHERE D.DEPTNO = employees.DEPTNO) X
    ) AS DNAME
    FROM EMP employees 
;
```

Comment: Repeating DNAME isn't a problem as it's in different levels, and the innermost query doesn't require an alias. These changes don't hurt but also don't fix the problem, which is that `employees` is not visible in a nested subquery.